# multiple checkboxes that will display different divs when checked

Tags: asp.net, forms, checkbox

i have about 10 checkbox options. the user can select just one or multiple. And when checked, different things will show.

so i have this working for getting one checkbox with the name "checkbox", but i need help on getting it so that it will work for 10 different checkboxes?

```
function showMe (box) {      
var chboxs = document.getElementsByName("checkbox");
var vis = "none";
for(var i=0;i<chboxs.length;i++) { 
    if(chboxs[i].checked){
     vis = "block";
        break;
    }
}
document.getElementById(box).style.display = vis;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the element to the function, get the id (element.id).
And then have a list of divs with corresponding id="div1"
Maybe try something like this:

Javascript:

```
function showMe (element) {
    document.getElementById("div" + element.id).style.display = (element.checked) ? "block" : "none";
}
```

HTML:
`<input type="checkbox" onclick="showMe(event.target)" id="1">`
`<div id="div1" style="display:none">you clicked checkbox 1</div>`